# jQuery masonry initializes failing on subsequent calls

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I am experiencing something that I believe shouldnt be happening (based on other comments around the internet).

Basically the first time I call masonry() the layout is fine.

But if i re-emit new html content (for the masonry container) and then initialize it via masonry() again, then the layout is broken (just grid layout, but doesnt fill in all the spaces between items).

On IE8 i actually get a jquery.masonry error via the debugger.

- Am i doing something fundamentally wrong?
- Is there a better way to do this?

  ```
  var $container = $('#container');

  // emit photos.
  $container.html(content.join(''));

  // initiate masonry.
  $container.imagesLoaded(function() {
      $container.masonry({ // <<------------ this is where is crashed on subsequent attempts.
              itemSelector: '.item',
              isAnimated: true,
              isFitWidth: true
          });            
  });
  ```

*** Update ***

I am now able to get subsequent masonry init's to work (the masonry layout is working).
To do this I simply call .masonry('destroy') before emitting new html content to the masonry container. Not sure why this making it work as nobody else seems to be doing this.

Comment: No. I cant figure out how to use jsfiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just replacing the contents of the container, as opposed to the container itself, you will have to call `.masonry('destroy')` before initing it again.

Comment: Sorry, I just read your update and see that you already figured this out. You can add an answer if you want; its perfectly acceptable to answer your own question.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. This should be documented somewhere imho.

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar You'll run into this a lot because the plugins will generally bind some information to the container using `.data()` or by saving a reference to the container in some object. You need to clear out that information before initializing again.